# How to use a common clipboard for vim and Unity?

Tags: unity, vim, clipboard

On my mac I solved the problem this way:

```
:set clipboard=unnamed
```

On my debian I use the + clipboard:

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

However the methods above don't work on my Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity desktop environment. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vim, the `"+` [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) points to the system clipboard by default. But it sounds like you already know that.

That register probably isn't working because you need to install the gvim alternative. The default vim can't interface with the X clipboard (eg `"+p` will fail). Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

The command `vim` will be updated to use gvim instead, and you should be able to yank from and paste to your system's clibpoard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this with gvim and it worked for me. Will use it instead of default vim.

Comment: Do you know how to get this to work in a terminal vim? (Not gvim) I have installed vim-gnome and my `vim --version` includes `+xterm_clipboard`, but the `"+` and `"*` registers work only in gvim as expected, not in vim.

Comment: @PhilippWendler Hm, that's odd, it **should** work. Can you post the output of `readlink -e /usr/bin/vim`? Perhaps your alternatives system is launching the wrong thing when you call `vim` in the terminal.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards The output is `/usr/bin/vim.gnome`. This is the one which lists `+xterm_clipboard`, and which I use. Running `:version` inside my vim also shows it. Any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards Ah, I found a relict in my .vimrc which is the culprit (I copied my .vimrc from some website long ago): `set clipboard=exclude:.*` Thanks for trying to help me.